# R: hard code the content of a variable inside a function

Tags: r, function, namespaces, nse

I would like to create a function using the value stored in a variable, but in a way that I paste the "content" of that variable rather than the variable call, so that once the variable is re-assigned, the function doesn't change.

Is there an elegant way of doing that?

```r
var <- 3
f <- function(x) var + x

f(1)
#> [1] 4

var <- 1

f(1)  # I would like the output to stay the same, i.e., the function to be "fixed" after its creation
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Why not using a `var=` argument `f <- function(x, var) var + x;var <- 123;f(1, var=3)`?

Comment: What do you mean that the output should stay the same? You need a 2 or a 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R you would create a closure using one of these methods. You could define a local environment and copy `var` there

```
f <- local({var; function(x) var + x})
```

Or you could do a similar thing with an in-line function

```
f <- local({var; function(x) var + x})
```

Or you can split that version up into a generator function

```
make_f <- function(var) function(x) var + x
f <- make_f(var)
```

All of these will freeze the value of `var` inside the function `f`.

You could also write a helper function that would be more explicit about the environment creation

```
freeze_var <- function(fun, ..., .env=environment(fun)) {
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  dnames <- sapply(mc$..., deparse)
  fenv <- new.env(parent=.env)
  list2env(setNames(list(...), dnames), envir = fenv)
  environment(fun) <- fenv
  fun
}
```

Then you could use it to wrap any function with any variable(s)

```
var <- 3
f <- function(x) var + x
ff <- freeze_var(f, var)

f(1)
# [1] 4
ff(1)
# [1] 4

var <- 1
f(1)
# [1] 2
ff(1)
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compute on the language:

```
var <- 3
f <- function(x) var + x
body(f)[[2]] <- var

f
#function (x) 
#3 + x

f(1)
#> [1] 4

var <- 1
f(1)
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you exactly mean with the output staying the same:

Here we could do:

```
f <- local({
        a <- new.env()
        if(!exists('z', a)) a$z<-var
        function(x)x+a$z})
var <- 3
f(1)
#[1] 4
var <- 1
f(1)
#[1] 4  # Did not change (BUT WHY WOULD YOU WANT THIS BEHAVIOUR?)
```

Why would you want the same output? You would rather use the value 3 in the function

```
f <- function(x) x + 3
```

or even lock the variable to prevent any changes to it. ie any change to the variable will throw an error

```
var <- 3
lockBinding('var', globalenv())
f <- function(x) x + var

var <- 1# will throw an error.
```